# Different results in floating point division

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Why is the last digit different in each calculation below? Shouldn't they be the same?

```
1.0 / 3   # => 0.3333333333333333
10.0 / 3  # => 3.3333333333333335
100.0 / 3 # => 33.333333333333336
```

Comment: No. Because relative floating point precision cannot represent every number - the last digit differing is because that's the "part" affected by the truncation effect. So many duplicates. - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (The encoding is in base2, not base10).

Comment: Because 10 isn't a power of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.0/3 * 10 == 10.0/3 # => false
```

Floats are inaccurate, therefore, in current versions of Ruby the use of Rationals is simplified:

```
1/3r * 10 == 10/3r # => true
```

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, this leads to many surprising situations.

I advise to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You can solve most of this problems by using `BigDecimal` instead of floats

```
require 'bigdecimal'
BigDecimal.new(  '1.0') / 3    #=>  0.333333333333333333
BigDecimal.new( '10.0') / 3    #=>  3.333333333333333333
BigDecimal.new('100.0') / 3    #=> 33.333333333333333333
```